# Most concise way to identify a certain page in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now, if I want to verify if a specific page is requested in the view, e.g. `users#show`, I would use this code:

```
if params[:controller] == "users" && params[:action] == "show" then ...
```

**Is there any other, more concise, way to identify if a certain page is requested?**

Comment: You're going about it wrong. You should declare in your router which page gets rendered when, and write code in your views that isn't dependent on the controller/action. separate your concerns appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I'm experimenting with that now, passing a parameter in `router.rb` dependent on page requested. And then evaluating in the view: `params[:passed_param]`. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use controller.controller_name and controller.action_name also

Answer (score 0):

You could use `current_page?` in your view to do this:

```
if current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'show') then ...
```

You could also use `user_path(user)` as an argument to `current_page?`. Here is some documentation on this [helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F).

Hope this helps!